# Issue Displaying Japanese Characters in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

My ecliplse IDE is displaying junk characters instead of the correct japanese characters...

Tried many strategies , my encoding is set to UTF-8...but still no outcome.

Screenshots for references are attached..

[image: Junk Characters in my String.xml]

[image: Version of eclipse that i am using...]

Any help will be accepted... 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open this file in your Workspace directory: `<your_workspace_dir>\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime\.settings\org.eclipse.ui.ide.prefs`
2. Append this line to that file: `IDE_ENCODINGS_PREFERENCE=EUC-JP'Shift_JIS'`
3. Restart Eclipse
4. Open Setting: Window > Preferences > General > Workspace > Text File
   Encoding. In `Other:` select "EUC-JP" in dropdown.
5. Ok -> re-open that file;

Answer (score 0):

The xml file might be saved as SJIS(MS932).

Maybe this page can help you:
http://internetmarketingcoding.com/how-to-convert-japanese-shift-jis-text-to-utf-8

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the eclipse.ini config file in the eclipse home folder
2. Add the new  parameter -Dfile.encoding=SJIS
3. Close and Open the eclipse.