# How to display Japanese character in eclipse

Tags: java, string, eclipse

I am using eclipse Juno as Java IDE and in my java code comments and logging statement are in Japanese.

eclipse is displaying junk character instead of correct Japanese characters. I followed  [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15221546/issue-displaying-japanese-characters-in-eclipse) to resolve the issue and made changes in eclipse.ini file. But now I am getting **String literal is not properly closed by a double-quote** error.

Comment: did you try setting a japanese font in eclipse inside preferences>general>appearance>colors and font?

Comment: May  this  link help you to resolve your problem.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14772275/utf-8-text-hindi-not-getting-displayed-on-browser-window-or-eclipse-console

Comment: @pratZ I did not find any Japanese font option in preferences>general>appearance>colors and font.

Comment: @AnkurLathi Thanks, issue got resolved by setting UTF-8 encoding in Preferences>General>Workspace>Text file encoding>other>UTF-8

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to tell eclipse to use UTF-8 for its stdout console. You can set that by Window > Preferences > General > Workspace > Text File Encoding.

[image]